# AppEngine bulk loader and automatically created property values

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bulkloader

In my model I have a property:

```
created = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

When an object of this type is created in the datastore, the *created* property is automatically populated.

When I use the bulk loader tool with a table which does not have this field, the field is not automatically populated when I upload to AppEngine, at which time new objects are created.

How can I make it set the *created* time on new objects uploaded from the bulk loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like the following to bulkloader.yaml:

```
- property: created
  external_name: created
  import_transform: "lambda x: datetime.datetime.utcnow()"
```