# How to upload current date/time into App Engine with Bulkloader tool?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

How can I add a last modified time property to my entity kind that gets updated during a bulk upload?

I'm currently using appcfg upload_data to upload a csv up to my high replication datastore. I plan to have this as a cron job to do a one-way sync from our internal database to datastore. In order to account for stale records, I'd like to have it update a last modified time property and then do a map reduce to delete old records (older than a week). Records will be updated using key property.

What would be the best way to create the last modified time considering I want to reserver the ability to use the Datastore Admin to delete the entire entity kind if I need to?

- Create a object model to "initialize" the datastore entity with all the necessary fields?
- Add a property to my bulkuploader.yaml for the modified time and use a import transform to get the date?
- Other...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

> Add a property to my bulkuploader.yaml
>   for the modified time and use a import
>   transform to get the date?

Comment: This was also asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766055/appengine-bulk-loader-and-automatically-created-property-values. Would there be a way to set the current date time to a variable so its not repeatedly running the function?